# Setting value of key in nested object happening incorrectly using a for loop and if statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, if-statement

Here is an example that you can type in your console. Super new to Javascript. The example is reproducible by opening a new tab and typing it out in a console (The JSX Fiddle's console feature is in beta, so I'm not sure if it can be trusted)

```
let clothing = ['card0', 'card1', 'card2', 'card3'];
let timers = {}
let timerObj = {"startTime": null, "pauseTime": null, "elapsedTime": null, "hasSubmitted": false} //Nested object I want for all indices, will manipulate 0th index alone inside for loop

for (var i = 0; i < clothing.length; i++) {
  timers[i] = timerObj
  if (i == 0) {
    timers[i]["startTime"] = Date.now();
  } 
} 
console.log(timers)
```

What I'm intending to do is, for the 0th index alone, set the `timers[0]["startTime"]` as `Date.now()`, and for the rest, let the `startTime` be `null` as defined in the `timerObj`.

Strangely, after running the for loop, I see that for all `i`, the `Date.now()` has been set. I understand that Javascript objects are mutable, but why is why are all indices being set to `Date.now()`?

I looked at other Javascript related `Object` questions related to a concept call "freezing", not sure I have my basics right.

EDIT: I think this is related the object reference being altered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var clothing = ['card0', 'card1', 'card2', 'card3'];
var timers = {}
var timerObj = {"startTime": null, "pauseTime": null, "elapsedTime": null, "hasSubmitted": false} //Nested object I want for all indices, will manipulate 0th index alone inside for loop

for (var i = 0; i < clothing.length; i++) {
  timers[i] = Object.assign({}, timerObj)
  if (i == 0) {
    timers[i]["startTime"] = Date.now();
  } 
} 
console.log(timers)
```

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for more information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not copy objects. It passes references around, so when you assign `timers[i] = timerObj` once, then you assign `Date.now()` once , this value goes to your single `timeorObj`. All subsequent assignments of `timerObj` to `timers[i]` for all `i` refer to the single `timerObj` you defined.

To fix this force a copy:  `timers[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(timerObj));`

This will serialize your clean `timerObj` to a JSON string, then convert it back to a new javascript object and then assign the new object to `timers[i]`.

This way, you end up with copies of `timerObj` in each slot of your `timers` array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone your `object`. There are multiple ways to clone. One would be `spread operator(...)`. Like below:

```js
let clothing = ['card0', 'card1', 'card2', 'card3'];
let timers = {}
let timerObj = {"startTime": null, "pauseTime": null, "elapsedTime": null, "hasSubmitted": false}

clothing.forEach((val, i)=>{
    timers[i] = {...timerObj};
    if(i==0){
       timers[i].startTime = Date.now()
    }
});
console.log(timers);
```